# Parsing "enum" options with optparse-applicative

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

How do I implement a parser for this example from `grep --help`:

```
 --binary-files=TYPE   assume that binary files are TYPE;
                       TYPE is 'binary', 'text', or 'without-match'
```

Assuming that I have

```
data BinaryFiles = Binary | Text | WithoutMatch
```

How do I write a parser? `option auto` seems a kludge since `Read` is supposed to be an "inverse" to `Show`, and I'd like to keep the derived `instance Show BinaryFiles`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `str` instead of `auto`:

```
binFile :: ReadM BinaryFiles
binFile = str >>= \s -> case s of
    "binary"        -> return Binary
    "text"          -> return Text
    "without-match" -> return WithoutMatch
    _ -> readerError "Accepted binary file types are 'binary', 'text', and 'without-match'."
```